# Questions About an Appropriate Textbook on Electrochemistry for Self-Study

Tags: electrochemistry, reference-request

Apologies if this is a somewhat frequent request (I promise I did scour various sources before posting, but none quite applied to me), but I was hoping for some insight from the community regarding an electrochemistry textbook that I could self-study.

To give some background, I am an electrical engineering student with a minor in physics (and I have in the past taken courses in organic and physical chemistry, although that was some time ago so I forget much, if not all of that) who is interested in learning more about batteries. I am ultimately interested in their operation as storage for large-scale renewables, but I would love a deep understanding of the electrochemistry involved beforehand. I've never been happy with the hand-wavy explanations that I've seen in the past, so I wanted something fairly rigorous.

My thought was to read McQuarrie's *Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach* first (this would be a good accompaniment to my actual courses in quantum and statistical mechanics at any rate, presumably with more of a high-level focus on the chemistry which would be an interesting angle). If this is a bad idea, please let me know!

Where I am more lost is in the next step, in picking up a book that looks virtually only at electrochemistry. I've come across three books which are listed below, but I am not sure about which would be appropriate or if anyone has some insight as to why I should pick one over another.

1. *Electrochemical Systems* by Newman
2. The venerable *Electrochemical Methods: Fundamentals and Applications* by Bard and Faulkner (I'll probably get this at some point no matter what, but I'm interested in what would be a best touch with electrochemistry after McQuarrie).
3. *Physical Electrochemistry: Fundamentals, Techniques, and Applications* by Eliaz and Gileadi.

Comment: While Bard and Faulkner are respectable electrochemists, *Electrochemical Methods: Fundamentals and Applications* their book is not meant for the faint hearted. It is not meant for self-study either. Have you checked Bockris and Reddy's Modern Electrochemistry Vol 1 and Vol 2. It has more of a talking style.